# Is there a plan to provide the Trending sort option to sites other than Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, sorting

Stack Overflow has recently unveiled the Trending sort option, that weighs votes cast recently heavier than those cast earlier, in order to promote fresh answers showcasing new techniques over stale answers based on outdated technology.

Though I was rather sceptical initially (and I still hardly consider it perfect), I think it could mitigate at least some cases of the [FGITW problem](/q/9731/620615), especially on sites where scores are prone to being biased by drive-by HNQ votes.  Trending sort could weigh votes accumulated organically heavier relative to those received when the question is fresh, while in HNQ.

Is there a plan to introduce this sort option to other Stack Exchange sites?

Answer (score 6):

The latest I've seen about this is [this comment by staff member Kyle Pollard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418767/trending-a-new-answer-sorting-option?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment915683_418767):

> @Laurel we don't have immediate plans to bring it to the rest of the network, but I think that there's value for having it on some sites. We want to evaluate its performance on Stack Overflow during the first few months before we consider it on other network sites.

The performance [has been evaluated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418766/4751173) so it might be considered for other sites in [6-8 somethings ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/295232)